# WatiN : Textfields are not getting automated while running the code as

Tags: c#, testing, watin

WatiN.Core.IE window = new WatiN.Core.IE();

```
            // Frames



            // Model

            TextField txt_txtName = window.TextField(Find.ByName("txtName"));

            TextField txt_txtPassword = window.TextField(Find.ByName("txtPassword"));

            Button btn_btnLogin = window.Button(Find.ByName("btnLogin"));



            // Code

            window.GoTo("http://134.554.444.55/asdfgfghh/");

            txt_txtName.TypeText("fghfjghm");

            txt_txtPassword.TypeText("gfhgjfgh");

            btn_btnLogin.Click();

        }
```

only the  window.GoTo("http://134.554.444.55/asdfgfghh/"); code works and the rest are doing nothing,

When I am using a catch block it throws exception as

Could not find INPUT (hidden) or INPUT (password) or INPUT (text) or INPUT (textarea) or TEXTAREA element tag matching criteria: Attribute 'name' equals 'txtName' at "http://134.554.444.55/asdfgfghh/ (inner exception: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'mshtml.IHTMLElement'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{3050F1FF-98B5-11CF-BB82-00AA00BDCE0B}' failed due to the following error: Error loading type library/DLL. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80029C4A (TYPE_E_CANTLOADLIBRARY)).)

Comment: the find will not work before the goto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call Button, TextField or whatever it does not create mapping it actually searches for control on page. And if the page is not opened yet than control does not exist.

You can create properties that will find control when you request it. So you define a particular model as class with appropriate properties.

```
public TextField txt_txtName
{
    get
    {
        return window.TextField(Find.ByName("txtName"));
    }
}
```

**Added**: If creating properties does not work for you, then use this:

```
var model = new
{
    txt_txtName = new Func<TextField>(() => window.TextField(Find.ByName("txtName"))),
    txt_txtPassword = new Func<TextField>(() => window.TextField(Find.ByName("txtPassword"))),
    btn_btnLogin = new Func<Button>(() => window.Button(Find.ByName("btnLogin")))
};

window.GoTo("http://134.554.444.55/asdfgfghh/");

model.txt_txtName().TypeText("fghfjghm");

model.txt_txtPassword().TypeText("gfhgjfgh");

model.btn_btnLogin().Click();
```

Comment: Its not working for me, by the way as I said, the page opens up for the given URL, so it should be able to find the control by its ID or by its name

Comment: I updated my answer and added example. Does it works well for you?

Answer (score 4):

My answer is very similar with Pavlo's one, but I must advice to use `Page` which is a built-in suport for `Model` as described by Pavlo.

Create a class MyPage

```
public class MyPage : WatiN.Core.Page
{
    public TextField NameField
    {
        get { return Document.TextField(Find.ByName("txtName")); }
    }

    public TextField PasswordField
    {
        get { return Document.TextField(Find.ByName("txtPassword")); }
    }

    public TextField LoginButton
    {
        get { return Document.Button(Find.ByName("btnLogin")); }
    }
}
```

Then you can just call `.Page<MyClass>` method.

```
using(var browser = new IE("http://134.554.444.55/asdfgfghh/"))
{
    var page = browser.Page<MyClass>();
    page.NameField.TypeText("name field");
    page.PasswordField.TypeText("password field");
    page.LoginButton.Click();
}
```

Comment: One suggestion - especially for common functions such as logging in, add helper methods to the Page implementations. In Baptiste's example above, you could add a method Login(string name, string password) which sets the name and password fields with the provided values, and clicks the login button. That way you can handle multiple scenarios (entering invalid usernames, expired passwords etc) with minimal duplication.